# Python 2.x return values for cmp

Tags: python, python-2.x

Quoted from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#cmp):

> `cmp(x, y)`
>
> Compare the two objects x and y and return an integer according to the outcome. The return value is negative if `x < y`, zero if `x == y` and strictly positive if `x > y`.

I was under the assumption that the return values are always `-1`, `0`, and `1` but the docs don't explicitly say that, only mentioning zero and positive/negative return value.

Are there any situations when the return value of `cmp(x,y)` is not `-1`, `0`, or `1`?

Comment: Naturally it's worth noting that using `cmp()` is advised against, as it is gone in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the docs explicitly say that yalues can be anything. The only value that is specified is `0` if the compared objects are equal. Don't trust the fact that you only see the values `-1`, `0` and `1`, that's an implementation detail and could change*, so always check for `<` and `>` 0.

*: note - actually, it won't really have a chance to change, since `cmp` has gone away in pyhton3. use [rich comparison](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Only 0 can be relied on, although the docstring for `list.sort` is interesting:

```
print list.sort.__doc__
L.sort(cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) -- stable sort *IN PLACE*;
cmp(x, y) -> -1, 0, 1
```

But in fact, sort doesn't actually impose this on it's comparison function as can be seen here:

```
def mycmp(a, b):
    print "mycmp(): a - b = ", a - b
    return a - b

L = [50, 30, 20, 40, 70, 50]

>>> L.sort(cmp=mycmp)
mycmp(): a - b =  -20
mycmp(): a - b =  -10
mycmp(): a - b =  20
mycmp(): a - b =  10
mycmp(): a - b =  -10
mycmp(): a - b =  30
mycmp(): a - b =  20
mycmp(): a - b =  10
mycmp(): a - b =  -20
mycmp(): a - b =  0

>>> print L
[20, 30, 40, 50, 50, 70]
```

Just for interest, but clearly `sort` is working happily with values other than `-1`, `0`, or `+1`, so you should be too!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted says that the sort builtins accept cmp functions that can return +, 0 or - results.